# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'db_user'@'ip' (using password: YES) while connecting to a RDS DB instance using IAM DB Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, amazon-aurora, amazon-policy

*Following is a quick summary of the question. Read the full description section for the underlying details.*

### Condensed description:

Assume you have an IAM user already existing and the user is already able to access other AWS services, such as S3, CloudFront, ECS, EC2...

Let's say we need to provide the user with read-only access over the RDS cluster and set up IAM DB Authentication as well.

We perform all the steps mentioned as per the official guide, in OUR local system and it works perfectly and we are able to generate correct auth token for `db_user`.

However, here is where it gets interesting.. when the user tries to generate the token for the `db_user` account, from their local machine.. the user will be denied access.

---

### Full description:

#### Setup:

My RDS cluster instance runs the Aurora MySQL engine. 
Engine version: 5.6.10a

I've been following the AWS knowledge center guide on [How do I allow users to connect to Amazon RDS with IAM credentials?](http://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/)

The guide doesn't explicitly mention but while generating the authentication token, AWS CLI uses IAM credentials stored locally, to sign the request.

I'd like to highlight that in the below-mentioned snippet, **admin** is the profile name stored by AWS CLI for my admin IAM user while the **db_user** is the IAM user (with `rds-db:connect` privileges).

`TOKEN="$(aws --profile admin rds generate-db-auth-token -h.. .. .. -u db_user)`

Using the above snippet I'm able to authenticate with the generated token and connect to the cluster.

If `--profile` attribute is not mentioned, it reads the default profile saved in the credentials file.

#### Issue:

Instead of using `--profile admin` I'm looking to use an already existing non-admin IAM profile for generating an authentication token.

For instance, assume IAM user named **developer**, with RDS read-only privileges and the credentials stored locally under the profile **rds_read_only**

`TOKEN="$(aws --profile rds_read_only rds generate-db-auth-token -h.. .. .. -u db_user)`

If I use the above token, I get the following error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'db_user'@'ip' (using password: YES)`

After hours of troubleshooting, I was able to conclude that my **rds_read_only** profile is unable to generate valid authentication tokens probably because IAM user **developer** is missing some required policies.

I tried attaching all policies available under `RDS` and `RDS Data API` (individually as well as in combinations) to IAM user **developer**, without any luck. If I attach the `AdministrativeAccess` policy to IAM user **developer**, only then it is able to generate the token successfully.

#### Question:

What are the mandatory policies required for non-admin IAM users to generate an authentication token successfully?

Answer (score 0):

i saw your question in AWS Blog.

1. You need to create an IAM policy to define access to your AWS RDS instances. Check this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html)

   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "rds-db:connect"
               ],
               "Resource": [
                   "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-2:1234567890:dbuser:*/*"
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
2. Create User inside RDS DB instance with the instructions to use an IAM Plugin. Check this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.DBAccounts.html)
3. Create the token check this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.AWSCLI.html)
4. I found this [nice plugin](https://github.com/rikturnbull/iam-jdbc-driver) that builds a JDBC jar to allow IAM authentication.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my question. I'm already able to do this.

Comment: yes sorry. I Actually need to test a very similar scenario but with the possibility of connecting using MySQL workbench . One thing i can ask you to check is something called AWS IAM trust relationship. Is in the AWS IAM Role. You might need to enable a trust relationship with AWS RDS

Comment: Ah! I'm not sure if the trust relationship is aimed towards accomplishing the motive, but it certainly gives me hope, to go and try that. Thanks, mate. Really thanks.

Comment: i will keep you updated when i try this. Also check AWS forums i saw some references to similar annoying issue.

Comment: Believe me, I skimmed through more than 300 threads posted in that forum. Almost everyone was struggling with getting the initial setup to run properly. The posts, where I could vaguely or remotely relate my situation with, were unanswered. That's why I really appreciate you taking the time to answer this thread.

Comment: Yup. I will check tomorrow bro and let you know

Answer (score 0):

This answers the specific question of @Ronnie regarding the Token generation.

Ronnie i am back. I used the following policy in my AWS Account: Sandbox I am an AWS Federated user with AssumeRole priveleges so `Admin`

You have to be very careful because as you said the article doesn't make the distinction from:

**AWS IAM USER using a generated token to access the DB** and

**AWS IAM User/Role with the right Admin policies that generates a VALID Token**

I will give an Example of how to identify the correct generated Tokens. For some reason AWS generates a value but it doesn't tell you whether is a useful token or not :-\

**Token without admin special access=** *WILL NOT WORK*

```
sandboxdb.asdasdffw.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/?Action=connect&DBUser=human_user&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA5XZIHS3GYVMRPRZF%2F20200424%2Fap-southeast-2%2Frds-db%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200424T035250Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=3efd467d548ea05a8bdf097c132b03661680908f723861e45323723c870ef646
```

**Token with Access=** *Will Work!* Look carefully and it contains **X-Amz-Security-Token=**

```
sandboxdb.ras21th1z8.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/?Action=connect&DBUser=human_user&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA5XZIHS3GSAQI6XHO%2F20200424%2Fap-southeast-2%2Frds-db%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200424T040756Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEEQaDmFwLXNvdXRoZWFzdC0yIkgwRgIhAOzVIondlMxYkJG5nWNeQlxS0M6B1pphgD1ewFwx2VfKAiEAkcp2jNHHmNMgwqUholnW545MwjzoEjS1uh4BHI4R4GAqvgMIbRABGgw5NDQ0NDAzMTc2NDUiDEvFkyEy833kd%2By4nyqbAybqK5dcP0nTlqZ19I2OVZxzwzz%2BUv9RVdVLMPHE5b%2FqXQGVG1CRtw90r9Lt4QkzTBeIVzdtIkXbpwFtqFh24Djb%2BiZHfvElj%2Fhz29ExzStU0fPYMewEB1u%2F2Osi72Fw6KbZ6TDy5EjuWcrrS08PZQ9CHc%2Fc8iDAIKs28vJ70KKcmow0SInVZGHGpD2JAgIL7jvnadVlcAW7lN2OAnxS72Kb4neqNuHcWzfPLfbXaOP1OaOs7vCR7zDlTTxX2aHoVflC69K9K67BqzdnDnnju%2F4XWQWU3r%2ByXylExwOsiG3y4Qq6wv002l%2BpQmF5%2BMXdTrFR5ewpfrcHf8TZLI5eq8HLA2gG1%2B255L%2Bqt%2BD80T%2FCzEdKSJPjppdYSq9FdeCMRSsqp5PpXP%2BDbQZwmhxiE2RmrbOKwNsFPJqUUnemQHXYLB8lily56nnswT2PYmQOGHqnZWRrv%2FTlGOAGlThuiR%2BLhQLBC08nBEGbBqK%2FjU4JwFMY4JfhgUHr8BA9CuGwAu0qIAFzG71M3HzCNX6o56k1gYJB%2F3%2FJaKlp7TCIxIn1BTrqASqywcfKrWhIaNX3t%2BV%2FZoYYO%2FtGVBZLyr3sSmByA%2Fwq538LiPHA0wDE3utOg%2FwNP%2BQGTcXhk1F%2BI0HOHztAQ2afnKW8r1oRbXxYAzb2j2b8MNEwrsaBju2gHFRgZHkM8YI%2FP5cvYr%2F8FQXWcE9eqjdme0hOo3rPETzxZfRwNQTHEntBbVVD1ec0d7DblfSEDZhLk%2By1%2BFMAYf7NeBIfU6GNsAN2hTdSkPPuto2fQKzRybRAwxQz5P3cO5CClUNIxu4J3bM1MUUTux%2BtMjqRvjGxDhB4yLIJmIPOOYLDSOXl3aWO2y4v89wu5A%3D%3D&X-Amz-Signature=1c6fcc472bb2af09055117075ca21d4a5f715910443115116c9230905721e79d
```

**AWS IAM policy For DB User to Connect to AWS RDS DB Instance**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds-db:connect",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

To avoid messing with local configs i used the following testing process:

1. Token generation from an AWS EC2 instance running in the same VPC as the DB. Generation is successful
2. Token generation from local machine by using a Docker container with [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-docker.html) Token generation is successful.

Of course my user was created in the MySQL DB with the following command

```
mysql -h $HOSTNAME -u$ADMIN_USER -p$ADMIN_PASS <<EOF
CREATE USER db_human_user IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin AS 'RDS';
GRANT SELECT ON $SPECIFIC_GIVEN_DB.* TO 'db_human_user';
EOF
```